# How to get if an application user liked application page with new Graph Api version >= 2.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Before I could get this information from:

GET /{user-id}/likes/{page-id} HTTP/1.1
with application token

or

GET /me/likes
with user access token, then check if graph api returns application page's information.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/likes

Now it looks like it is not possible to get if an user liked application page using graph api's new version.

I don't want to get user_likes permission because it needs review and says:

"Please note that using user_likes to check if someone has liked your Facebook use case is not approvable. The user_likes permission provides information to all of a person's likes, and the entirety of this data should be used to enhance the app experience."

here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login

My case:

I have a custom like page UI in my Unity game and I want to show the UI according to this information. This is important for me because I want to reach my audience, I want to make some announcements or events from my application page. I have no interest on all of the user likes, I just need if my application user liked my application page, if this is true show my custom like UI (overlay on Facebook html UI), otherwise hide it (because a user could easily dislike the page mistakenly).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not be possible as described in the [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog/)

> In versions previous to v2.2, it was possible for an app to see if a person like the app's page by checking the `page_fan` FQL table or the `/{user_id}/likes/{app_page_id}` Graph API endpoint without needing the `user_likes` permission. Starting in v2.2, the `user_likes` permission will be required to query these endpoints. Also, we will require the user_likes permission on versions older than v2.2 starting 90 days from today, on Jan 28, 2015. Facebook will not grant the user_likes permission solely for the purpose of checking if a person has liked an app's page. This change was announced on August 7, 2014 and will come into effect on November 5, 2014.